# Cron job to execute jar file weekdays local time 8am-5pm, no weekends

Tags: cron, java

Okay so say I have a java program compiled as a jar file. I want to run four instances of this cron job to execute this jar file every Monday-Friday local time from 8am to 5pm, but at intervals of 30 mins, 1 hour, 4 hours, and 8 hours, respectively. How would I accomplish this?

```
*/30 8-17 * * 1-5 java -jar queryTickets.jar "critical" >/dev/null 2>&1
0 * * * 1-5 java -jar queryTickets.jar "high" >/dev/null 2>&1
0 */4 * * 1-5 java -jar sendNotifications.jar "medium" >/dev/null 2>&1
0 */8 * * 1-5 java -jar sendNotifications.jar "low" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Are these correct? Which folder should I put my jar files in on my Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Every 30th minute of every hour from 0800 to 1700 on weekdays:
*/30 8-17 * * *5  <<command>>

# Hourly, weekdays
0 * * * 1-5 <<command>>

# Every four hours, weekdays
0 */4 * * 1-5 <<command>>

# Every eight hours, weekdays
0 */8 * * 1-5 <<command>>
```

As for the command to run, if your `jar` file doesn't care about or takes care of its own working directory, you can simply run `/path/to/jre/bin/java -jar /path/to/my.jar "option" > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Ah I just realized I need to install a Java JRE on my Ubuntu server, is that correct?

Comment: If you want to run Java, you need a Java Runtime Environment, yes.

Comment: Okay cool. I can install that with a simple Unix command?

Comment: Yes; on Ubuntu, `apt install openjdk-9-jre`.